# How to fix compile error; 'Wrong number of assignments or invalid property assignment' error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Type Coordinate
    x As Double
    y As Double        
End Type

Type Point
    name As String
    c As Coordinate
End Type

Sub Custom_Var()

'Declare p1 as UDT point
Dim p1 As Point

'Assigning the values
    p1.name = "A"
    p1.c.x = 2.5
    p1.c.y = 3

'Print out the values to spreadsheets
Cell(1, 1) = p1.name
Cell(2, 1) = p1.c.x
Cell(3, 1) = p1.c.y


End Sub
```

Comment: You have a typo... Change `Cell` to `Cells`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Even with the typo, I get a different error message (sub or function not defined).  Without the typo, it works OK.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55514496/edit) to include the error you are getting and the row which is throwing the error.

Comment: Strange, works for me with the Cells change.

Comment: @SJR Yes, it works for me too, with that change.  But I never see the error message posted by the OP, even without that change.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - yes agreed, I get the same message as you. Perhaps the code posted is not quite as is.

Comment: @SJR thanks so much for your answers. I have resolved. My type statements were misplaced at end of a function above the code I posted.

Comment: OK, I am voting to close this question as the problem was caused by a relatively simple typographical error, and this resolution is unlikely to help others in the future.